# P-depletion of Siegel modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, siegel-modular-forms

Let $F$ be a cuspidal Siegel modular form of genus 2 (of parallel weight $(k, k)$, and level some congruence subgroup $\Gamma \subseteq Sp_4(\mathbf{Z})$ of level $N$).

Then $F$ has a series expansion
$$ F(Z) = \sum_{T} a_T(F) \exp(2 \pi i \operatorname{tr}(T Z) ) $$

indexed by matrices $T$ of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b/2 \\ b/2 & c \end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbf{Z}$ and $\det(T) > 0$.

Let $p$ be a prime not dividing $N$ and let 
$$ F^{[p]}(Z) = \sum_{\substack{T \\ p \nmid \det(T)}} a_T(F) \exp(2 \pi i \operatorname{tr}(T Z) ). $$

Is $F^{[p]}$ also a Siegel modular form? What is its level?